# How do I get my Code to show only one picture per question

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const question = document.querySelector('#question');
const choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice-text'));
const progressText = document.querySelector('#progressText');
const scoreText = document.querySelector('#score');

let currentQuestion = {}
let acceptingAnswers = true
let score = 0
let questionCounter = 0
let availableQuestions = []


let questions = [
    {
        question: "Question 1",
        choice1: "Spain",
        choice2: "France",
        choice3: "Colombia",
        choice4: "China",
        answer: 2,
    },
    {
        question:"Question 2",
        choice1: "Hungary",
        choice2: "Switzerland",
        choice3: "Chile",
        choice4: "Austrailia",
        answer: 1,
    },
    {
        question: "Question 3",
        choice1: "Chile",
        choice2: "Brazil",
        choice3: "New Zealand",
        choice4: "Morocco",
        answer: 4,
    },
]
const SCORE_POINTS = 1
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 6

function startGame(){
    questionCounter = 0
    score = 0
    availableQuestions = [...questions]
    getNewQuestion()
}

function getNewQuestion(){
    if(availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter > MAX_QUESTIONS) {
        localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score)
        return window.location.assign('end.html')
    }
    questionCounter++
    progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter} of ${MAX_QUESTIONS}`
    // progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter/MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`
    
    const questionsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length)
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionsIndex]
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question

    choices.forEach(choice => {
        const number = choice.dataset['number']
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number]
    })

    availableQuestions.splice(questionsIndex, 1)

    acceptingAnswers = true
}

choices.forEach(choice => {
    choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if(!acceptingAnswers) return

        acceptingAnswers = false
        const selectedChoice = e.target
        const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number']

        let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'

        if(classToApply === 'correct') {
            incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS)
        }

        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply)

        setTimeout(() => {
            selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply)
            getNewQuestion()

        }, 1000)
    })
})

function incrementScore(num){
    score +=num
    scoreText.innerText = score
}

startGame()
```

```css
body{
    background-color: gray;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5.4rem;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
h2{
    font-size: 4.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.flex-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-center{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.justify-center{
    justify-content: center;
}
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.btn{
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    padding:2rem 0;
    width: 30rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(29, 26, 26);
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: teal;
    box-shadow: rgb(130, 170, 183);
    transition:transform 150ms;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.btn[disabled]:hover{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: none;
}
body {
    color: black;
}
.choice-container {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: lightblue;
    font-size: 3rem;
    min-width: 80rem;
}

.choice-container:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(6, 103, 247, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.02);
    transform: transform 100ms;
}

.choice-prefix {
    padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
    color: black
}

.choice-text {
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}
.progressText{
    text-align: center;
}
.correct {
    background: green;
}

.incorrect {
    background: red;
}

/* Heads up Display */
#hud {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.hud-prefix {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.hud-main-text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
    <style>
        img{
            align-self:  center;
            width: 80px;
            height: 150;
            padding-bottom: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
            <div id="hud">
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
                        Question
                    </p>
                    <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Score
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                        0
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 id="question">What is the answer to this question</h1>
            <img id="france" src="france.jpg">
            <img id="hungary" src="hungary.jpg">
            <img id="morocco" src="morocco.jpg">
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Flag.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Im creating a quiz game that shows the user a country flag and the user has to choose from four choices to pick the correct one. Currently I have all the questions flags being shown because I cant figure out how to show just one image per question. Is there a way to hide the other pictures or put the image to specify an image to a question. The quiz also randomizes each time you play so if the first time you play is different the second time.

I added a code snippet of just the flag questions. my entire code as a home page and an end page that shows the final score and lets the user play again.

Comment: Please add a code snippet, that is, if you can. The edit function isn't working for me.

Comment: All of your images have the same id which will be a problem soon enough.  I would recommend putting the picture you want displayed inside your questions array.  You could dynamically change the src of a single, existing image or generate images on the fly.

Comment: Posted a codepen, and solution steps. Please click the checkmark to the left of answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: https://codepen.io/chrisbradshaw/pen/yLaLLVo.

1. Remove the flag images from HTML and add:

```
<img src="" alt="quiz show question" id="flagImage" />
```

2. Include flag image in question objects:

```
    {
        question: "Question 1",
        choice1: "Spain",
        choice2: "France",
        choice3: "Colombia",
        choice4: "China",
        answer: 2,
        flagImage: 'https://placekitten.com/200/300'
    }
```

3. Create a variable for `#flagImage` DOM img:

```
const flagImageHtml = document.querySelector('#flagImage');
```

4. Update the src of the `#flagImage` DOM img when you change the current question:

```
flagImageHtml.src = currentQuestion.flagImage;
```